# Syntax highlighting for build.gradle with Prism

Tags: gradle, build.gradle, prismjs

For displaying a build.gradle sample code on my blog, I want to syntax highlighting with [Prism](https://prismjs.com).

But gradle is not included in the supported languages list. Are there any `language-xxxx` alternatives to highlighting gradle? Using `language-nginx` is a good choice?

---

Updated 2022-05-04:

You are now available Gradle thanks for the module's author
ABDELKHALEK ZELLAT.

Comment: Well, Gradle uses a DSL based on Groovy (or Kotlin), so you may use the highlighting for those languages.

Comment: @LukasKörfer, thank you! I've tried both of `language-groovy` and `language-kotlin`, your answer is right (if you post your comment as an answer I'll accept it).

Comment: @hata Prism now is supporting Gradle :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Gradle uses a domain-specific language (DSL) based on Groovy, so the `language-groovy` tag should highlight language elements like strings and braces. However, it won't highlight keywords related to Gradle, like `task` or the `plugins`, `repositories` and `dependencies` blocks. As those blocks may be added dynamically by third-party plugins, this is not possible for a syntax highlighter at all.

Please note that Gradle provides an alternative DSL based on Kotlin that requires the `build.gradle` files to be restructured and renamed to `build.gradle.kts`. For those files, the tag `language-kotlin` might work even better.